# Scala mocking trait that is extended by another trait

Tags: scala, mockito, traits, scalatest

I am trying to test

```
trait Name extends Helper {
    def name() = {
      var s = getSystem()
      s.name()
    }
}
```

where all I want to do is make sure that the "s.name()" method is invoked once by mocking an instance of s, which is a System.

Helper is defined as so:

```
trait Helper {
    def getSystem() : System = {
       systemGetter.get()
    }
}
```

As of now, my NameSpec looks something like:

```
class NameSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers with MockitoSugar {

    class NameImpl extends Name
    var toTest = new NameImpl

    val mockSystem = mock[System]

    it should "call s.name() once" in {
        when(getSystem() is invoked, return a mockSystem) 
        toTest.name()
        // Verify that mockSystem.name() happened only once
    }
}
```

What I'm confused about is how to return a mock System in toTest.name() when it calls getSystem() so that I can verify that the system calls s.name() only once. I could easily mock this System if it were a parameter to the name() method in Name trait, so I guess I don't know how to "inject" a mockSystem to be used instead of a real system when that method is invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately your code is not compilable and thus is obviously an inadequate representation of what you really have. Particularly it is not clear how the `Helper` really gets an object of type `System`. I think that in the real code you should mock the `systemGetter`, that I suppose is somehow injected into the objects implementing `Helper` trait, to return your `mockSystem`. However it is hard to show you a valid example of that basing on the code you provided. If for some reason this is not what you can do, there are a few more avenues.

You seem to use something like Cake pattern around `Helper` and its inheritance. If so, you can use a class instead of `NameImpl` to inject `System`:

```
class NameWithInjectedSystem(val system: System) extends Name {
  override def getSystem(): System = system
}

it should "call s.name() once" in {
  val mockSystem = mock[System]
  val nameToTest = new NameWithInjectedSystem(mockSystem)
  val mockName = "Mock name"

  when(mockSystem.name()).thenReturn(mockName)
  val actual = nameToTest.name()
  actual should === (mockName)
  verify(mockSystem, times(1)).name()
}
```

Finally you can mock even `nameToTest` object itself but this is not the way I'd suggest because it binds test to much more implementation details than you should want:

```
it should "call s.name() once" in {
  val mockSystem = mock[System]
  val nameToTest = mock[NameImpl]
  when(nameToTest.getSystem()).thenReturn(mockSystem)
  when(nameToTest.name()).thenCallRealMethod()
  val mockName = "Mock name"
  when(mockSystem.name()).thenReturn(mockName)
  val actual = nameToTest.name()
  actual should ===(mockName)
  verify(mockSystem, times(1)).name()
}
```

Note how you must call `thenCallRealMethod` for the `.name()` call and so you should do for all the calls inside the `name` or the test will not work.